# google.com search suggestions not showing in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am experiencing an weird problem in Chrome. When I go to www.google.com, I search something, but I don't get any auto search suggestions / autocomplete suggestions. I tried with both google.no and google.com. None works. But I get this feature in all other browsers even in Chrome in my PC. It only doesn't work in Chrome in my Macbook pro. I have uninstalled Chrome, cleared all application data and re-installed the latest version, but no luck. This is so annoying. It started before a month ago, and I cannot solve this problem. Also it works fine in a incognito window. Is there a solution?
Thanks in advance.

*Note: I am not talking about the chrome addressbar. I am talking about when you go to www.google.com and search something in there.*

Comment: *it works fine in a incognito window*...perhaps you have a misbehaving add-on? Try disabling all of them.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the history (cookies etc.) in Chrome?

Comment: often some data is still stored in computer even after you uninstalled a product. you can try few things. Try different chrome edition (like beta version/developer edition or something), use different chromium browser, easiest to try is clearing your cache and user folders then uninstall finally reinstall